java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator when upgrading log4j from 1.2.16 to 2.20.0
I have to upgrade log4j from version 1.2.16 to 2.20.0 in codebase of a legacy system. During the upgrade, upgrading spring security from version 4.1.1 to 5.2.15 is also required. Updated dependencies are shown below.
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.15.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.15.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.15.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>

When I start the application, there are NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException.
14:46:10,354 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."cas-ear-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.ear".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."cas-ear-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.ear".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "cas-ear-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator
    at org.jboss.as.logging.deployments.LoggingConfigDeploymentProcessor.configure(LoggingConfigDeploymentProcessor.java:239)
    at org.jboss.as.logging.deployments.LoggingConfigDeploymentProcessor.processDeployment(LoggingConfigDeploymentProcessor.java:113)
    at org.jboss.as.logging.deployments.LoggingConfigDeploymentProcessor.processDeployment(LoggingConfigDeploymentProcessor.java:141)
    at org.jboss.as.logging.deployments.AbstractLoggingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AbstractLoggingDeploymentProcessor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator from [Module "org.jboss.as.logging" version 16.0.1.Final from local module loader @604ed9f0 (finder: local module finder @6a4f787b (roots: C:\wildfly-24\cas\wildfly-24.0.1.Final\modules,C:\wildfly-24\cas\wildfly-24.0.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 13 more

From the stacktrace, org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator can't be found so there is ClassNotFoundException. Since PropertyConfigurator is from log4j 1.2.16 but not log4j 2.20.0, the existence of ClassNotFoundException  implies there are some places still importing it from log4j 1.2.16. However, I've updated all relevant imports from old version to new version and searched whole codebase and find no codes still using the old version of log4j.
I've stuck for a few days and done researches on the Internet and still can't figure out the reason. Would someone please help?

By curiosity: why do you upgrade to Log4j Core 2.20.0, which is already 18 months old? Do you expect an easier upgrade path? Log4j is versioned semantically, so there are no breaking changes between version 2.20.0 and version 2.24.1.

The decision on which version should be upgraded to was made by my senior. Since the application is old, I think compatibility to other dependencies the application currently uses may be one of the considerations. @PiotrP.Karwasz

Although we always declare the latest dependency versions in our releases, Log4j Core will work with pretty old deps. If you find a bug in 2.20.0 (or worse a vulnerability), you will need to upgrade to the latest version to have it fixed. Although we apply strict semantic versioning in Log4j with no breaking changes in minor versions, mistakes happen and something could break.

Just an update. Today I was asked to upgrade log4j from version 2.20.0 to the latest stable version 2.24.1. I finished the upgrade from version 1.2.16 to 2.20.0 in codebases of 5 legacy systems two weeks ago. It wasted my time. @PiotrP.Karwasz

FYI: there is a critical bug in 2.24.1 that causes null loggers to be returned (see #3143), please upgrade to 2.24.2 instead.

As you can see the exception does not come from your application, but from the LoggingConfigDeploymentProcessor class of your application server.
To find the reason of the error, look at the Per-deployment Logging section of your Wildfly Admin Guide: if use-deployment-logging-config configuration property is set to true (default), the container will look for files like log4j.properties in your application.
To solve the problem, remove your log4j.properties file from either the WEB-INF or WEB-INF/classes (classpath) folder of your WAR file.

You're so amazing and your solution works. I'm a junior Java developer and would you please teach me how to know to find the Per-deployment Logging section of the Wildfly Admin Guide to find the solution? @Piotr P. Karwasz

The approaches vary, personally I start with the source code of the class that caused the exception. If it is OSS, it's code is probably on GitHub and you can see why the code was executed in the first place. Then you can find a doc reference and hide your traces. ;-)
